# Eloquent team-based roles

Tags: laravel, eloquent, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have 3 tables: Roles, Teams, Users with a pivot table between each: role_team, role_user, team_user.

I'm having a hard time leveraging Eloquent to return only the roles that a user has for a specific team.

```php
$team = Team::find(1);
foreach($team->users as $user) {
    dump($user->teamRoles); // Get the roles this user has for the team
}
```

While I could do `$user->roles()->where('team_id', $team->id)->get()`, I'd like to specify it as a relationship. I tried setting up a `hasManyThrough`, but it doesn't seem to work in this specific case.

The need to use this as a relationship rather than query is because I'm using Lighthouse PHP for GraphQL and would like to easily be able to query for the roles like:

```
teams {
  id name 
  users {
    teamPivot {
      roles { id name }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help leveraging Eloquent to make this happen would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution, though not necessarily the one I'm looking for is to use the `@method` directive on a field.

Imagine the following schema:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  teams: [Team] @belongsToMany
  teamMeta: TeamUser
}

type Team {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  users: [User] @belongsToMany
  userMeta: TeamUser
}

type Role {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  team: Team @belongsTo
  users: [User] @belongsToMany
}

type TeamUser {
  user: User!
  team: Team!
  roles: [Role] @method(name: "getTeamRoles")
}
```

Where `getTeamRoles` looks like:

```php
public function getTeamRoles()
{
  return $this->user->roles()->where('team_id', $this->team->id)->get();
}
```

This configuration will allow  the following GraphQL to work as desired:

```
  users(first: 1, input: { id: 2 }) {
    email teams {
      name userMeta {
        contactedAt
        roles { id name }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is currently the solution I'm running, but it would be nice to have a "pure" Eloquent answer for this instead of having to write a custom accessor for each relation of this type.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can achieve what you want by using `Many to Many` relationship.

Basically you will need to define write a method that returns the result of the `belongsToMany` method in both `User` and `Roles` models.

It will be something like this:

In `User.php`

```
 public function roles(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
 }
```

In `Role.php`

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Then, you will be able to do something like:

```
$team = Team::find(1);
foreach($team->users as $user) {
    dump($user->roles); 
}
```

For more reference you can see the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

I hope this helps.

Comment: This returns all of the user's roles without the team constraint. See the answer I posted to better understand why this one doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry @Nathan - this part of the code `$team = Team::find(1);` threw me off, because with that part of the code you will always have team constraint. 

Now I see what you're talking about. 

You should maybe try to create scoped query like here: 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes

You should be able to create method `scopeOfTeam($query, $teamId)` and then you will be able to do something like `User::ofTeam($teamId)->roles`

It's not 100% clean eloquent solution, but it will create cleaner code for you. 

I hope this is something you can leverage.

Comment: Thanks Ben, unfortunately the constraint isn't consistent so it's not possible to make a scoped query for this instance.